# ZipArchive extractTo() not working with URL

Tags: php

I am trying to extract a `ZipArchive` to `'http://localhost/MODULES/ZIP_RAR_MANAGER/'`.

No errors are shown, and I get the message `Zip File Opened`.

Why are the files not being correctly extracted from the zip archive?

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open('../test.zip')) 
{
    echo 'ZIP FILE OPENED...<br/>';

    if ($zip->extractTo('http://localhost/MODULES/ZIP_RAR_MANAGER/'))
    {
        echo 'ZIP FILE EXTRACTED';
    }

    $zip->close();
} 
else 
{
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: Extract to a filesystem directory, not to a URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to extract it to non-existent folder `http://localhost/MODULES/ZIP_RAR_MANAGER/`. You cannot use url as a folder/file path.

You should use:

```
if ($zip->extractTo($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/MODULES/ZIP_RAR_MANAGER/') {
...
}
```